# Error Processing Archive - Installing CUDA on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, cuda

I am installing CUDA 11 on Ubuntu 20.04 using

```
sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

It gives me the following error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
cuda is already the newest version (11.0.3-1).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-drivers-450 : Depends: libnvidia-common-450 (>= 450.51.06) but it is not going to be installed
 libnvidia-gl-450 : Depends: libnvidia-common-450 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

To install the libnvidia-common-450, I used `sudo apt-get install libnvidia-common-450`

Output is as follows:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-common-450_450.51.06-0ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-450.51.06-key-documentation', which is also in package libnvidia-common-450-server 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-common-450_450.51.06-0ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I downloaded installer from Nvidia but installation has the same error. Can anyone help resolve this? Thanks

Comment: `apt --fix-broken install` (as suggested by the error message) indeed fixed a similar situation for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to this issue: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/problem-with-apt-and-nvidia-440-on-ubuntu-20-04/115281/2

Can be solved by running:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-common-450_450.51.06-0ubuntu1_all.deb
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
```